# Embedding Images in Blackberry Emails

Tags: image, blackberry, html-email

Is it possible to have an image automatically embedded in an email, which when opened on a Blackberry will show by default without the user having to open it seperately?

I'm constructing a HTML email eshot that will be opened on Blackberry devices with the below HTML:

```html
<html>
   <style>
      body {background-color: Black; color: #fff;}
   </style>
   <body>
     <table align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
       <tr>
         <td><img src="cid:Eshot.jpg" /></td>
       </tr>    
     </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

This works when viewed Outlook but I'm not sure whether I can get it to render on Blackberry devices without it effectlvely being an attachment. I'm aware that Blackberry devices handle HTML emails in there own unique way, but the client it is being produced for has apparently had emails in the past where it has been embedded but I'm not sure what I can do if anything to force this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032509/blackberry-embedded-browser-image-display-using-html/9092899#9092899) how I solved it and try if it fits your needs. Shortly, you need to convert the image in a bytestream and include it in your html body as:

```
... <img src="data:image/bmp;base64,gzfddr56utggtlytlgg....jigkgfjytdjyr"></img> ...
```

where:

```
gzfddr56utggtlytlgg....jigkgfjytdjyr
```

is the encoded image bytestream.

Comment: The solution seems to work for web pages but it doesn't seem to render the images in emails in either outlook or on blackberry devices.